# Change image styles based on selected theme

Tags: 7, theming

I have multiple themes under one installation and using SwitchTheme http://drupal.org/project/Switchtheme to switch between themes as selected by the user. My problem is I have a view displaying thumbnails that need to change color depending on current theme selected.

Anyone have any suggestions or know of a module out there to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: you can use views tpl and put it in each theme folder for this view.

Comment: thanks Sibiraj, I guess I may need to create a custom module using image_style_url() and hook_views_pre_render(), is this the best way? or is it all done in the tpl file? not too sure where to start

Comment: What do you mean with image styles? In drupal7 image styles may be the old d6 image cache. If you want to change the color it looks like a css issue. Give us more information please.

Comment: D7 images styles is a part of core.. cheers