# Hiding an image field based on theme in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

I want to hide an image field(field_image) of a node when a different theme is selected.

How can I do it?

I'm not able to find any sample code in internet but I know it can be done both in tpl.php and template.php files.

Comment: By which way do you change theme on your site?

Comment: Using https://drupal.org/project/mobile_theme. I want to hide images in mobile devices to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in node.tpl.php

```
hide($content['field_image']);
```

or in hook_preprocess_node

```
hide($variables['content']['field_image']);
```

It works with views as well if you are using content row plugin.
For fields you have to override views-view-fields.tpl.php and remove image field from $fields variable.

```
unset($fields['field_image']);
```

Also take look at this modules:

https://drupal.org/project/cs_adaptive_image

https://drupal.org/project/adaptive_image

Comment: Thanks can you pl. tell me how to hide a views field similarly?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Can you pl. also answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65526/change-image-styles-based-on-selected-theme ? I want to change image style to small image for mobile devices. Those adaptive_image modules I don't want because I simply want to show desktop images in 1/3 of their size on mobile devices. These modules will only resize image if it is greater than screen size. In my case it's all logos of small size which should change to even smaller size in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the current theme with this code (inside your template for example):

```
<?php global $theme; ?>
```

Then you can do

```
<?php if($theme=="my_awesome_theme") { render($item); } ?>
```